# Camel LoadBalancing & Failover Handling

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am working on a project where we need to parse a file of size > 2GB and load data into DB. I am planning to break file using camel splitter into 50 different files and then process each one using Apache Camel.

My question is:

If while processing one of the file, camel route fails then how can I stop the camel route and audit this in DB with file name. It might happen that some of the records are processed and uploaded to DB and for a specific records it is failing to load in DB. So we need to log this specific record in some other file.

Also while processing, if support due to network failure DB operations are stopped then in this scenario file processing is incomplete. So how to handle this incomplete file processing scenario as only remaining records should be processed again.

Comment: Perhaps you better should use a Batch framework such as Spring Batch (that can be integrated in Camel too).

Answer (score 1):

As you intend to split the incoming file I assume your records have no inter-dependencies.

Instead of splitting the large file into many files and then process them while trying to keep some context of the original file you could use the splitter to split your large input file line by line. The splitter can be used in streaming mode to not load the large input file into memory first. Then put every line on a SEDA/message queue. On the receiving end use concurrent consumers to get the parallel processing.

The file component sets an exchange header with the currently processed file name. The header should be preserved during splitting and transfer. If one of your consumers fails, the error handler of the consuming route should have the information of the source file name for logging purposes. Your consumers will keep processing messages even though one message might have failed processing. So there is no need to figure out where to pick up processing.